# UISplitViewController: how to prevent detail view to be reinitialized each time?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

A `UISplitViewController` is created through the `storyboard`.

I would like to pass data to the detail view, when interacting with the master view, without reinitialize it every time the `segue` is called.

However when the `segue` is called, a new detail view controller is initialized and added. It looks like this is default behaviour. How to prevent this?